# Repeat calling of a DoubleAnimation while it is running

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DoubleAnimation` call that is triggered on a button press.  One button press causes the control to fade in (1000 milliseconds), pressed again it causes it to fade out (500 milliseconds).  Now I notice if a user spams this button it will not fade back in.  I have no problem with it ever failing to fade out. If the user then clicks again, which toggles the trigger, then clicks once more with a brief (~1 second) pause between clicks the control will then fade in without issue.

```
private void fader(bool fadeOut)
{

   if ((!fadeOut && gripLbl.Visibility == Visibility.Hidden) ||
       (fadeOut && gripLbl.Visibility == Visibility.Visible))
             return;

   if (fadeOut)
   {
        // Fade in grip
        gripLbl.Opacity = 0;
        gripLbl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        gripLblAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
   }
   else
   {
        // Fade out grip
        gripLblAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        gripLblAnimation.Completed += delegate
        { gripLbl.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; };
   }

   Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(gripLblAnimation, 60);
   gripLbl.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.OpacityProperty, gripLblAnimation);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, the only thing I can seem to find that helps is turning down the fade out timer down below 100 milliseconds.  But if possible I would like it to just stop the current animation if it is in progress and start the new one.

I have tried nulling it out, starting a new `BeginAnimation` with the second parameter being null and using `.Freeze()` before hand in an attempt to cancel the current animation with no luck.

Comment: Yes, I am just doing this all pragmatically because I found it to be easier with the variables I end up using and such.  And to be honest I'm just not familiar enough with WPF having recently just moved from WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to incorpate a flag for when it's fading. Something like:

```
bool fading = true;
```

So that at the start you can put:

```
if(Fading) return;
```

That way if the user is mashing the button it will keep returning (i.e. ignoring them) until the fading boolean is reset at the end of the fade.

```
fading = false;
```

Comment: My mistake, I have a basic check which I think is good enough?  I really just use it to save the unneeded execution of the function. But it does not catch this, which isn't really the problem because I do not want to ignore the request.  I want to stop the current fade and start a new one.  I edited my sample code.

Comment: Is your variable 'fadeOut' static?

Comment: fadeOut is fed in as a parameter.

Comment: A possible solution to stop it dead in it's tracks and start again would be to attach the process to a thread. That way the thread can be paused or terminated and of course new ones can be created.